# QCamera: failed to start

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt5

Не получается запустить камеру. Даже стандартный пример не работает:

```
\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.6\qtmultimedia\multimediawidgets\camera\
```

На строчке `camera->start();` всегда в консоль выводится:

> failed to start

Во время дебага при вызове `camera->start();` выводится:

> defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"

`camera->error();` возвращает:

> QCamera::ServiceMissingError

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Вероятнее всего проблема в ваших драйверах, либо в этой версии qt, либо в порте под python, ибо у меня на Qt 5.5.1 C++ всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: Я пишу под Windows (8.1) и пытаюсь запустить вебкамеру ноута, к слову. Пробовал запустить на другом ноутбуке (Windows 7) и тоже самое.

Comment: У меня тоже ноутбук, Samsung, вебка WebCam SC-13HDL11939N, Windows 8. Ну если так, то скорее всего дело в вашей версии Qt.

Comment: Я попробовал в разных версиях.

Во время вызова `camera->start();` выводится:


`defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"`


А `camera->error();` возвращает:

`QCamera::ServiceMissingError`

Comment: Скачал Qt 5.5.1 - тажа проблема.

Comment: Возможно не находит directshow.

Comment: @alexis031182 Я скачал сорцы `qt` с `directshow`, но как правильно собрать? Пытаюсь построить через `qt creator`, но не появляется `dll`.

Comment: @ГригорийНиколаевич , а что Вы хотите собрать? Сам Qt, его плагин к DirectShow? Я думаю, что не стоит этим заниматься. На мой взгляд, в Вашей ОС просто не хватает установленного DirectShow (и это нормально, ибо, как мне известно, он давным давно устарел). Возможно даже, что установка какого-нибудь набора кодеков, типа k-lite, поможет в ситуации. QtMultimedia не развивается, отсюда и проблема. Если Вам нужен видеозахват не просто на поиграться, то лучше посмотрите в сторону других фреймворков, так как QtMultimedia очень ограничен, а под виндовс даже в большей степени.

Comment: Установка кодеков не помогла. 
А какой фреймворк Вы можете посоветовать? Желательно, чтобы он умел работать с камерой и сеть и создавать gui. Мне нужно для написания курсовой, поэтому, можно сказать, для "просто поиграться".